# How to create Provisioning File

Tags: ios, iphone

I new to iOS development, and I want to run my app on my iPhone. I have connected it to my laptop but no prompts show up. I read all these tutorials on how to add a device and stuff but it really is confusing for me, because none of it is happening for me.

I am probably going to be down voted cause this is a stupid question, but my brain is rattled: How do I create a provisional file, and use a device for development?  Please make it really detailed, cause Apple's description are kind of vague.

(The thing is when I press the plus button in iOS Provisional Profile in Member Center, it can't detect a device that has been connected. If that way is wrong, you know why I am confuse.)

Comment: Have you followed Apple's instructions (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH1-SW1)? If so, which step exactly is giving you problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lot of steps to do to run iOS app into your Apple Device.

1) register to apple developer portal

2) enroll for iOS Developer Program, which will cost $99 per year

3) add your device to your account, create certificate & Identifiers. with all these create Provisioning Profile.

4) download the PP and install it to you device

5) Open you Xcode, -> Application -> Build Settings -> Code Signing: select you "Provisioning Profiles"

build and run.

Answer (score 0):

see the link it will help you

http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Provisioning-Profile-for-

if you want best

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppStoreDistributionTutorial/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile/CreatingYourTeamProvisioningProfile.html